Unable to use or list the mount points in databricks after enabling unity catalog
I have a databricks workspace where I have mounted my azure storage containers but after enabling unity catalog I am unable to list the mount points using dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/') unless until I have the admin access.
I have multiple scripts which are automated using adf so now I can't change the mount point to volumes
I have tried the below code to list the mount points but throwing below exception:
dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/') 


ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o438.ls.
org.apache.spark.SparkSecurityException: [INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS] Insufficient privileges:
User does not have permission SELECT on any file. SQLSTATE: 42501
at com.databricks.sql.acl.Unauthorized.throwInsufficientPermission


Error:

ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o438.ls. org.apache.spark.SparkSecurityException:  [INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS] Insufficient privileges: User does not have permission SELECT on any file.  SQLSTATE: 42501 at com.databricks.sql.acl.Unauthorized.throwInsufficientPermission

The above ERROR message suggest you are not having sufficient permissions.
To make sure that your user account is assigned with required roles assigned you can follow the below steps:
The below is my mount script:
configs={"fs.azure.account.auth.type":"OAuth",     "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type":"org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
         "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id":"<Your client ID>",  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret":dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<YOUR DATABRICKS SECRET SCOPE NAME >", key="<KEY VAULT SECRET NAME>"), "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Your tenant ID>/oauth2/token"}
dbutils.fs.mount(source= "abfss://rawcontainer@lambostg.dfs.core.windows.net",
                 mount_point="/mnt/raw",
                 extra_configs=configs)

I have assigned the KEY VAULT Administrator role to SPN & AZUREDATABRICKS app.

I have assigined Storage Blob Data Contributor role to SPN & AZUREDATABRICKS app.

Results:
dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/raw/')

[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/raw/sample_employee_data.csv', name='sample_employee_data.csv', size=813, modificationTime=1729745074000)]


thanks for the response @Dileep Raj Narayan Thumula , I just wanted to check that have you tried listing the mount points after enabling unity catalog in your workspace because before enabling uc I can be able to list the mount points also i have given the necessary permissions.

Hi Naveen Kumar reddy I am using UC enabled ADB

Hi Dileep Raj Narayan Thumula i have given Storage blob contributor. but still i am getting the same error.

have your provided storage blob contributor role to azuredatabricks app?

yesi i have given that role for spn and azuredatabricks app
